# Reading cmd output real time

Tags: c#, cmd

I'm writing a program that reads python script output and shows the results in textbox.
Since the script runnning for a long time, I want to be able to see the output every 1 second (or after each line is writen).
Now i can see the output only when the process ends.
Does someone know what is the problem?

snippet of my code:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
p.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler (p_OutputDataReceived);
p.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler (p_ErrorDataReceived);
p.Exited += new EventHandler (p_Exited);
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "python.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "path " + commandline; 
p.Start(); 
StreamReader s = p.StandardOutput;
String output = s.ReadToEnd();
textBox3.Text = output;
p.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm doing it the following way in my own programs:

```
private static void startProgram(
    string commandLine )
{
    var fileName = commandLine;
    var arguments = string.Empty;
    checkSplitFileName( ref fileName, ref arguments );

    var info = new ProcessStartInfo();
    info.FileName = fileName;
    info.Arguments = arguments;

    info.UseShellExecute = false;
    info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    info.RedirectStandardError = true;

    using ( var p = new Process() )
    {
        p.StartInfo = info;
        p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        p.OutputDataReceived += (s,o) => { 
            Console.WriteLine(o.Data);
        };
        p.Start();

        p.BeginOutputReadLine();

        p.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

I.e. I'm subscribing to the [`OutputDataReceived` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived) and calling [`BeginOutputReadLine` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline). See also [this similar Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631443/capturing-process-output-via-outputdatareceived-event).

(The method `checkSplitFileName` in my above source code [can be found here](http://pastebin.com/Tqw9cgJ3))

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem running my Python script from C#. The problem is that Python buffers the output from `stdout` (print()).

You could do one of two things here.

***1.***
Add the following to your Python script, after every `print()` line to flush the output.

```
import sys
print('Hello World!')
sys.stdout.flush()
```

***2.***
Run the Python compiler with the `-u` command line parameter. This way you don't need to add the above flush line after every print.

```
...
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "python.exe -u path " + commandline; 
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Python, by default, buffers its output.
The way to go is to pass a "-u" command line argument to python.

so if you want to execute say hello.py, you would do :

python.exe -u hello.py

Heres the C# code that works for me.

```
Process p = new Process();
string op = "";
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\\python27\\python.exe";
StreamReader outputStream = p.StandardOutput;
StreamReader errorStream = p.StandardError;
p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-u hello.py";
p.Start();
string output = "";
int offset = 0, readBytes = 0;
char[] buffer = new char[512];
do
{
    output = outputStream.ReadLine();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(output))
    {
        txtOutput.AppendText(output);
        txtOutput.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
        offset += readBytes;
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
    Thread.Sleep(3);
} while (!p.HasExited);
```