# Process exe stuck at specific files and how to move next file in the loop

Tags: c#, process

I am trying to run a process in my code looping through each file and performing some task. Sometimes the EXE gets stuck when it runs across some files. And this doesn't move forward. If this kind of situation occurs how can I skip the files which is stuck in the process and save the file into a TXT file which has failed. And further move with the next file for processing. I tried to check it online and didn't get much help. Please suggest how can I get this done?

```
foreach (var file in files)
{
  ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
  {
      FileName = exedir + "\\testing.exe",
      Arguments = "-a -h -i -l " + file,
      RedirectStandardOutput = true,
      UseShellExecute = false,
      CreateNoWindow = true
  };

  using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(processStartInfo ))
  {
      var line = string.Empty;

      using (StreamReader streamReader = exeProcess.StandardOutput)
      {
          while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
          {
             var content = streamReader.ReadLine();
         // Doing some task here
          }
      }
      exeProcess.WaitForExit(10000);
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you get any exception when the file is not processed? you should investigate why the process is stopping on a file. If that is caused by an exception, you can use a try..catch block

Comment: Additionally, the program you are starting from within your C# application might perhaps output something on standard error channel (stderr).
 Generally, i would like to advise you to run your program on one of the files it gets stuck with **not** from within your C# program, but rather manually from within a console window (with exactly the same command line parameters as shown in your code here). This could possibly give you a better picture of what is going on there (like seeing the program output without needing to redirect and read it from a stream)...

Comment: @GuillermoGerard: I dont get any exception when I run the exe manually too. It just hangs and doesnt give any output nor anything. So was looking for options to skip those files in the code which hangs.

Comment: @elgonzo: I tried that too. Below is a sample of how i get this. It doesnt throw any exceptions.                                           C:\test>testing.exe -a -h -i -l "D:\Aspnet.config"

Comment: Did you write that testing.exe program, or do you have access to its source code?

Comment: @elgonzo: No, I did not write it and dont have the source code as well.

Comment: Hmm, i can't give a definitive answer, but a suggestion that should be worth a try: First, don't read the output stream in a loop (which could block when the executed program gets stuck). Rather, use `OnOutputDataReceived` to collect the program output (like shown in this question+answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631443/capturing-process-output-via-outputdatareceived-event). (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) Second, you will need to check if your `exeProcess.WaitForExit(10000);` completes because the process exited or whether the timeout passed. If the process has not exited (= only the time-out passed), you will need to kill the stuck process (your `exeProcess` Process object provides properties and methods for that). However, be extremely cautious here. If testing.exe does any writing to some file, data corruption could possibly occur due to the killing...